# How to take a screenshot WITH a shadow on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of a window in Windows 10 using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Screen</kbd> and want to *retain* the shadow. I found this post, [How to take a shadowless screenshot on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/966789/how-to-take-a-shadowless-screenshot-on-windows-10), but I want to do the opposite.

Is there a way to take a screenshot of the active window using a keyboard command that will include the shadow?

See the drop shadow on this image as an example. (I created this by taking a full <kbd>Prt Screen</kbd> and cropping in Photoshop).

[image]

Comment: Any screenshot utility should capture exactly what you see on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a keyboard shortcut that will just capture the active window with the shadow. Question updated.

Comment: What do you mean by shadow? Are you talking about the border around it? The answer to that is already in the question you provided in the link.

Comment: Does alt+prtscreen work? I have shadows off.

Comment: The question you linked to was raised because Alt-PrtScrn captures the shadow and that author was looking for a way to avoid it.  Just don't do the solution to that question.

Comment: @DrZoo Added a link to an image. Tim Alt + Prt Screen saves the image _without_the shadow. fixer1234 Alt + Prt Screen does not seem to capture the shadow (see the last comments). I think it was an older build of Windows 10.

Comment: It does not capture the shadow on my W10 pc either, v10.0.10586

Comment: You seem to claim using Alt+PrnScr excludes the shadow, yet in your example pic (that you say to captured with Alt-PrnScr) shows the shadow..  Did you mean "Shift+PrnScr" in the last sentence?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the screenshot was taken with just Print Screen. Updated.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this? I have the same problem @Windows10User

Comment: @ErikBerkun-Drevnig No I did not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called Shotty that works: http://shotty.devs-on.net/en/Overview.aspx

Simply focus the window you want to take a screenshot of (no need to minimize any other windows) and press CTRL + PRT SCRN (the default hotkey using ALT instead failed to register for me because it is already being used by another program, I think just Windows 10). An image editor will open with your screenshot, including drop shadows. Click Save. (Copy to clipboard will not preserve transparency.)

Comment: You should edit your answer with a bit more information on how to use this screen capturing software in order to have windows shadows captured.

Comment: Shotty doesn't work on hidpi screens at least as of version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

alt+print retains the shadow by default.

Comment: On my PC, Alt + Prt Screen does not retain the shadow. (Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, build 10586.36.)

Comment: Are you sure you have shadows on?

Comment: Yes, if you view my screenshot (taken with just Print Screen and then cropped), you will see the shadow.

Comment: What about Shift + Alt + Print Screen?  Does it also provide the shadowless window?